# LINQ how to project a list while combining properties of object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to LINQ I am facing an issue.  How to create `List<SelectListItem>` from a linq query combining two properties of the object. for example create a `SelectListItem` of `employees` list but each select list item should have `Text = Emp ID + Name - "123 - Jack"`.

Comment: `employees .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Id + " - " +  x.Name)`

Comment: Can you please provide compilable sample input and output code, along with the required class definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<SelectListItem> result = employees 
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    { 
        Text = String.Format("{0} - {1}", x.EmpID, x.Name),
        Value = x.EmpID.ToString()
    })
    .ToList()
```

to remove duplicates as desired:

```
List<SelectListItem> result = employees 
    .Select(x => new { x.EmpID,  x.Name })
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    { 
        Text = String.Format("{0} - {1}", x.EmpID, x.Name),
        Value = x.EmpID.ToString()
    })
    .ToList()
```

Comment: I am getting duplicates with this. I tried using distinct but that doesnt help since I have new SelectListItem

Comment: @user2613228: have  a look.